# What is the best method to send data from a device to a server

Tags: http, post, csv, device

I am currently developing a website for an energy-monitoring company. We are trying to send high volumes data from the devices which record the data to a server so they can be processed in a database. The guy developing the firmware seems to think that the best way to send the data is to produce CSV files and send them via FTP. A program on the server needs to monitor the files received via FTP and run a PHP script to process them. I, however, feel that the best way of sending the data is via HTTP POST.

We had HTTP POST working and then I began trying to work with the CSVs which became a pain as reliably monitoring the files received via FTP meant editing the ProFTPD configuration file (which I found to be a near impossible task) and install a package called mod_exec (which comes with security risks) so that ProFTPD could run a PHP script. These issues and the fact that I am unfamiliar with the linux console which I am required to use extensively to set this up, makes the CSV method very difficult to set up. HTTP POST to me seems like a more direct way of sending the data without having to worry about files or relying on ProFTPD. It would also allow us to use identifiers to give the data being passed meaning as opposed to a string of values for which the meaning is not immediately apparent. In addition, the query string could be URL encoded to pass a multidimensional array which would work well given the type of data being passed.

Nevertheless, just because the HTTP POST method would be easier doesn't mean that the CSV method doesn't have advantages. Furthermore, the firmware guy has far more experience than me with computers so I trust his opinion.

Can you please help me to understand his point of view on the advantages of the CSV method and explain what the best method is?

Comment: HTTP. Period. Unless the people you're working with don't have the knowledge to implement it correctly. If that's the case, you're probably already in trouble :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. FTP has major issues with firewalls, and especially doesn't work well on mobile (NAT'ted) IPv4. HTTP POST works far, far better under such circumstances, if only because nobody accepts an "internet" connection that breaks HTTP.

Furthermore, HTTP is a lot easier on the device as well. It's just a single-socket protocol, with trivial read/write semantics on that socket.

Some more benefits? HTTP has almost-native support for compression (gzip). HTTP transmission can start before the input is complete. HTTP is easier to secure (HTTPS)...

No, there really is little reason to use FTP.

Comment: Thanks, is there any source you can provide so I can back up some of the things you said?

Comment: I am specifically referring to FTP having issues with firewalls. Also that nobody accepts an "internet" connection that breaks HTTP (I am not entirely sure what you mean by that)

Comment: @Josh'Bambi'Bambrick: For FTP sockets, see e.g. http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html. As for HTTP, no customer would accept an ISP firewall which blocks port 80, not even on mobile networks. But the inbound port for FTP often is blocked.

Comment: @MSalters when using HTTP POST is it better to send the data string using splitters or json? and why?

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury: Please ask a new question, these comments are to clarify my answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

The 'CSV method' (I'd call it the 'FTP method' though) has the advantage of being known to the embedded developer. The receiving side will have to create some way of checking if there is a file though. That adds complexity.

The 'HTTP method' has several advantages:

- HTTP is easy to implement on the sending side
- No need to create a file-checker
- You can reply to the embedded device if everything went OK

I actually just implemented a system just like that (not too much data, but still) and use HTTP POST to send the data. I implemented the HTTP POST myself.

Comment: Thanks, that is handy. I think we will now go with the HTTP method